# Load all related entities with Neo4jSessionFactory.queryForObject (or similar)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Using neo4j-ogm, I've written the following code, which contains two database calls. I would like it to only have one database call.

```
public Member loadMemberByDomainSpecificId(String domainSpecificId) {
        String query = "match (m:Member {domainSpecificId: {domainSpecificId}}) return m;";
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("domainSpecificId", domainSpecificId);
        Session neo4jSession = Neo4jSessionFactory.getInstance().getNeo4jSession();
        Member member = neo4jSession.queryForObject(Member.class, query, parameters);
        return super.find(member);
}
```

The first database call is

1. `neo4jSession.queryForObject(Member.class, query, parameters);`

The second database call is

2. `return (Member)super(find(member);`

`super` is `return session.load(Member.class, member.getId(), 1);`

where `session` is a `neo4jSession`.

I make the second API call because the first API call fetches only the node / object, and none of its related nodes / objects. The second API call refreshes the node and all its relationships.

**Does anyone know how I can efficiently do all of this with only one database call?**

queryForObject does not seem to support variable depth as many of the other neo4jSession methods do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all of the `Neo4jSession` operations take filters as formal arguments.

Filters allow you to select objects of a specified type (label) on one or more properties you're interested in matching. These operations return **all** matched nodes from the filter, along with their their related nodes, to the depth you specify (default depth = 1). So:

`Collection<Member> members = session.loadAll(Member.class, new Filters().add("domainSpecificId", domainSpecificId))`

should do what you need I think.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!